# AlertDialog wont work with custom layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, ratingbar

what i am trying to built a user-experience dialog with rating and comments.

I have built the dialog and everything works but when i press the possitive button it crashes for some reason...

My `onCreate()`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.user_profile);
        rateButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.rate);
        shareButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.share);
        ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
        ratingComment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ratingComment);
        ratingNum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ratingNum);
        ratingCommentText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Comment);
        setupButtonEvents();

    }
```

the `setupButtonEvents()`

```
private void setupButtonEvents() {
        rateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UserProfile.this);
                View newLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.rate_dialog,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.rootLayout));
                builder.setView(newLayout)
                        .setTitle(getString(R.string.rateDialogTitle))
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.posButtonRate, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                insertDataToDatabaseFromRating();
                            }
                        }).create();
                builder.show();
            }
        });
```

and the `insertDataToDatabaseFromRating()`

```
private void insertDataToDatabaseFromRating() {
        ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                percent = (int) ratingBar.getRating();
                ratingNum.setText("" + percent);
            }
        });
        comTxt = ratingComment.getText().toString();
        if (!comTxt.isEmpty()) {
            ratingCommentText.setText(comTxt);
        }
    }
```

The `Logcat out Error`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RatingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(android.widget.RatingBar$OnRatingBarChangeListener)' on a null object reference
            at com.order.app.order.UserProfile.insertDataToDatabaseFromRating(UserProfile.java:144)
```

Line 144: `ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {`

Can anyone help me out with this???
Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: I would recommend to extend `DialogFragment`. It is a far better and more object oriented way than `AlertDialog.builder.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `RatingBar` is inside `AlertDialog` layout. to access views from AlertDialog layout use view object which is passed in `builder.setView(newLayout)`.

In your case add View parameter to `insertDataToDatabaseFromRating` method then access `RatingBar` as:

```
private void insertDataToDatabaseFromRating(View view) {
 ratingBar = (RatingBar)view. findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
 .....
}
```

and pass `newLayout` object to `insertDataToDatabaseFromRating` when calling.

Do same for other views which want to access from `AlertDialog`

Comment: exactly i just saw that myself....silly i asked...but it does not count the rating can you help me with that?

Comment: @KostasMatrix: sure i will try please explain more about next issue